# How to create a Centos7 disk image based on aarch64 which can be used by qemu?

Tags: arm, qemu, diskimage

I want to test my kernel compiled for aarch64 with qemu vm.

I tried CentOS Cloud Image, but failed with a kernel panic during booting
[image]

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -cpu neoverse-n1 -M virt -m 1G -kernel kernel_for_arm/arch/arm64/boot/Image -nographic -drive format=qcow2,file=centosCloud/CentOS-7-aarch64-GenericCloud-2003.qcow2
```

I also tried boot with CentOS.iso trying to build my own disk image with the following command. But the terminal then get frozen without any output. VNC is not available on my machine.

```
qemu-system-aarch64 -boot d -cdrom CentOS-7-aarch64-Minimal-2009.iso -m 4096 -drive format=qcow2,file=CentOS7_mini.qcow2 -cpu neoverse-n1 -M virt -smp cpus=4 -nographic
```

**So I wonder how (or where) could I get a bootable CentOS7 disk image for my aarch64 qemu vm to boost?**